how to mysql database in django project
i set database connecting statement in settings.py it returns
no biulding tools and ask to install mysqlclient.
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?


You have to install mysqlclient package to use MYSQL in Django Project.
You can install the package by :
pip install mysqlclient

